# Need to convert object to array for FlatList in React Native

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have JSON **object** taken from Firebase real-time database. What I want is make an array from object and pass this array to state. Hence I want to pass this data to FlatList Component.

> This is how my **Object** looks like:

[image]

> Actually, I don't need keys, just like this ->

[image]

> I need your help because I just started to learn JS, before was programming on Android Studio

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use `Object.values` to get an array:

```
const array = Object.values( obj );
```